# jQuery Autocomplete textbox on selected events

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

How do I fire another event after I have completed the selection on the textbox that has autocomplete. I want to show a valid div area based on the selected value.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're talking about jQuery UI autocomplete, then like this:

```
$('#autocomplete').result(function(event, data, formatted) {
  alert('Someone picked a suggestion from the drop-down');
});
```

That is to say, the "result" method fires.

See http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete/autocomplete#options

Answer (score 1):

```
function change() {
  document.getElementById('<%=btnLoadBenefits.ClientID %>').click();
}

<asp:Button ID="btnLoadBenefits" runat="server" OnClick="btnLoadBenefits_Click" style="display:none;"/>    

<asp:TextBox ID="txtCompanyname" runat="server" Width="220px" Height="18px"                                                                                                MaxLength="50" onchange="change();">
</asp:TextBox>
```